# Rails - cannot override engine wrong one to many foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I have an engine that contains two tables, `seven_gallery_galleries` and `seven_gallery_photos`. I want to have one (gallery) to many (photos) relationship.

I have set the relationship and made my migrations, but I always get this error:

```
Unknown column 'seven_gallery_photos.gallery_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `seven_gallery_photos`.* FROM `seven_gallery_photos` WHERE `seven_gallery_photos`.`gallery_id` = 1
```

Here's my migrations:

```
class CreateSevenGalleryPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :seven_gallery_photos do |t|
      t.string :caption
      t.string :image
      t.references :seven_gallery_gallery, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

In **gallery.rb**:

```
has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy, , class_name: "SevenGallery::Photo", :foreign_key => "seven_gallery_gallery_id"
```

In **photo.rb**:

```
belongs_to :gallery, class_name: "SevenGallery::Gallery"
```

As you can see in `gallery.rb`, I have set a custom `foreign_key` to match the one created by the migrations, but apparently rails still looks for `gallery_id` instead of `seven_gallery_gallery_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you also needs to add :foreign_key in photo.rb

Comment: I did try this, but didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Looks fine to me. you can add more context in models, so it will help.